# contact form-7 drop downs not populating database

Tags: database, plugin-contact-form-7

I am using contact form 7 with Contact Form to DB Extension. I have this following code for my form. However when I to a test submit only the name and the address populate the database, there isn't even a column for the 4 drop down menus. Not sure why they don't populate the database?

```
<p>Select a day<br />
[select date id:day "Monday" "Teusday" "Wednesday" "Thursday" "Friday" "Saturday" "Sunday"]
</p>
<p>And a date<br />
[select date id:date class:date "1st" "2nd" "3rd" "4th" "5th" "6th" "7th" "8th" "9th" "10th" "11th" "12th" "13th" "14th" "15th" "16th" "17th" "18th" "19th" "20th" "21st" "22nd" "23rd" "24th" "25th" "26th" "27th" "28th" "29th" "30th" "31st"]
</p>
<p>Time<br />
[select date id:time class:time "10:00am" "10:30am" "11:00am" "11:30am" "12:00am" "12:30am" "1:00pm" "1:30pm" "2:00pm" "2:30pm" "3:00pm" "3:30pm" "4:00pm" ]
</p>
<p>How Many Bottles<br />
[select date id:bottles class:bottles "50" "60" "70" "80" "90" "100" "110" "120" "130" "140""150" ]
</p>
<p>Your Name</p><br />
[text name id:name]
</p>
<p>Your Address</p><br />
[text address id:address]
</p>
```

Comment: This is off-topic and too localized. You should try [Contact Form 7 Plugin support](http://wordpress.org/tags/contact-form-7?forum_id=10).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is most likely that you have given all 3 of your select fields the same identifying name "date".  Give them each a unique name and that will solve your problem.